# Translating and scaling a line based on two grabbed points

Tags: geometry, transformation

Say there is a line segment going from *0* to *10*, now imagine that point *7* and *8* are 'grabbed' and translated to respectively *6* and *11*. The effect would this would be that the line segment get's scaled and translated. How can I determine the new defining points of the new line segment.

[image: Line scaling and translation]

*Please note, in the above image there is only a x axis, no y axis.*

I believe this problem should be quite simple, but after trying out different things nothing seems to work. I suppose that I should calculate the scale $s = \frac{g_{1start}-g_{2start}}{g_{1end}-g_{2end}}$ and multiply that with $x_{1start}$ and $x_{2start}$ or something along those lines, but I just can't figure out how to approach this problem correctly (rather than guessing randomly).

Comment: You are very nearly there with your scale; the next thing is to apply the scale and offset to your $x_{1 start}$ and $x_{2 start}$ and you have your new endpoints.

Comment: Apply meaning what in thix context? Thats what I have been trying to figure out~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let

$$x_{new} = h_1 + (x - g_1) \frac{h_2 - h_1}{g_2 - g_1}.$$

where I've used $g_i$ for your starting points (7, 8) and $h_i$ for your ending points (6, 11). The formula shows how to take a point $x$ in the pre-stretch coordinates and tell its post-stretch coordinates. So

$$x_1^{end} = h_1 + (x_1^{start} - g_1) \frac{h_2 - h_1}{g_2 - g_1},$$

for instance, tells you how to transform the left end.